# Creating web application using python, html, jquery

Tags: jquery, python, html, web-applications

I am using bottle for the basic framework for the application. In the user's dashboard, the user can create notebooks, etc and all the metadata about notebooks, number of pages, etc is stored in a mysql database.

My question is whenever the user logs in to the site, the dashboard should be able to retrieve the amount of notebooks from the database and create them.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of [authentication](http://cork.firelet.net/) to identify and keep track of which user is creating a notebook on your  site.  When saving a notebook you could save the user who created the notebook along with the notebook data.  Then all you would have to do to get all notebooks a user created is to query your database

Comment: yes, I have already implemented this using cookies. Let me clarify my question: lets say the user created a new notebook, how do I add the html needed to show the notebook?

Comment: somehow the next time the user logs in, I need to know that this user has 7 notebooks and then show these notebooks on the site

Comment: @user3681650 you have to somehow associate the notebook with the user who created the notebook. Without providing more information and code it's difficult to tell you exactly how you should approach it.